# A simple Vector implementation

Tags: c++, vectors

Just made a simple `Vec` class, nothing fancy but I am open to suggestions for improvements. Of course, this is not suppose to replace or used for the same tasks as `std::vector`. This is more like opencv's `Vec` and eventually I want to include this in a bigger project of mine.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

#define VEC_ASSERT(x) assert(x)

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
class Vec {

public:

    typedef T           dataType;
    typedef T&          dataType_ref;
    typedef const T&    dataType_cref;

    // Empty Constructor
    Vec();

    // Single-Arg Constructor
    explicit Vec(T v);

    // From std::vector Constructor
    Vec(const std::vector<T>& v);

    // From std::initializer_list Constructor
    Vec(const std::initializer_list<T>& l);

    // Main Constructor
    template<typename ... Args>
    explicit Vec(T v, Args&& ... args);

    // Get vector dimensions
    unsigned int dim() const;

    // Get vector length
    double length() const;

    // Get vectors dist
    double dist(const Vec<T, C>& v) const;

    // Get the cross product (3D Vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> cross(const Vec<T, C>& v) const;

    // Get the dot product
    double dot(const Vec<T, C>& v) const;

    // Get ortho vector (2D vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> ortho() const;

    // Normalize vector values
    Vec<T, C> norm() const;

    // Rotate (2D Vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> rotate(double angle) const;

    // Rotate on x-axis (3D Vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> rotateX(double angle) const;

    // Rotate on y-axis (3D Vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> rotateY(double angle) const;

    // Rotate on z-axis (3D Vectors only)
    Vec<T, C> rotateZ(double angle) const;

    // Convert to std::vector
    std::vector<dataType> to_std_vector() const;

    // Cast
    template<typename TT, unsigned int CC = C>
    Vec<TT, CC> to() const;

    // Access vector values
    dataType_ref operator[](int index);
    dataType_ref operator()(int index);
    dataType_cref operator[](int index) const;
    dataType_cref operator()(int index) const;

    // Vector Operations with Scalars
    Vec<T, C> operator+(T v);
    Vec<T, C> operator-(T v);
    Vec<T, C> operator*(T v);
    Vec<T, C> operator/(T v);
    Vec<T, C>& operator+=(T v);
    Vec<T, C>& operator-=(T v);
    Vec<T, C>& operator*=(T v);
    Vec<T, C>& operator/=(T v);

    // Vector Operations with Vectors
    Vec<T, C> operator+(const Vec<T, C>& v);
    Vec<T, C> operator-(const Vec<T, C>& v);
    Vec<T, C> operator*(const Vec<T, C>& v);
    Vec<T, C> operator/(const Vec<T, C>& v);

private:

    // Recursive pusher (used by constructor)
    template<typename ... Args>
    void push(T v, Args&& ... args);

    // Base pusher
    void push(T v);

    // Vector values
    dataType values[C];

    // Index for Vector pusher
    unsigned int idx;

};

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>::Vec() {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] = 0;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>::Vec(T v) {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] = v;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>::Vec(const std::vector<T>& v) {

    VEC_ASSERT(v.size() <= C);

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
        this->values[i] = v[i];

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>::Vec(const std::initializer_list<T>& l) {

    VEC_ASSERT(l.size() <= C);

    unsigned i = 0;
    for ( auto it : l )
        this->values[i++] = it;


}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
template<typename ... Args>
Vec<T, C>::Vec(T v, Args&& ... args) {

    this->idx = 0;
    this->values[idx] = v;
    this->push(args ...);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
template<typename ... Args>
void Vec<T, C>::push(T v, Args&& ... args) {

    this->values[++(this->idx)] = v;
    this->push(args ...);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
void Vec<T, C>::push(T v) {

    VEC_ASSERT(this->idx + 1 < C);

    this->values[++(this->idx)] = v;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
unsigned int Vec<T, C>::dim() const {

    return C;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
double Vec<T, C>::length() const {

    double result = 0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result += this->values[i] * this->values[i];

    return std::sqrt(result);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
double Vec<T, C>::dist(const Vec<T, C>& v) const {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] - v[i];

    return result.length();

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::cross(const Vec<T, C>& v) const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 3);

    Vec<T, C> result;

    result[0] = this->values[1] * v[2] - this->values[2] * v[1];
    result[1] = this->values[0] * v[2] - this->values[2] * v[0];
    result[2] = this->values[0] * v[0] - this->values[1] * v[0];

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
double Vec<T, C>::dot(const Vec<T, C>& v) const {

    double result = 0.0;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result += this->values[i] * v[i];

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::ortho() const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 2);

    return Vec<T, C>(this->values[1], -(this->values[0]));

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::norm() const {

    VEC_ASSERT(this->length() != 0);

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] * (1.0 / this->length());

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::rotate(double angle) const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 2);

    double theta = angle / 180.0 * M_PI;
    double c = std::cos(theta);
    double s = std::sin(theta);
    double x = this->values[0] * c - this->values[1] * s;
    double y = this->values[0] * s + this->values[1] * c;

    return Vec<T, C>(x, y);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::rotateX(double angle) const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 3);

    double theta = angle / 180.0 * M_PI;
    double c = std::cos(theta);
    double s = std::sin(theta);
    double x = this->values[0];
    double y = this->values[1] * c - this->values[2] * s;
    double z = this->values[1] * s + this->values[2] * c;

    return Vec<T, C>(x, y, z);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::rotateY(double angle) const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 3);

    double theta = angle / 180.0 * M_PI;
    double c = std::cos(theta);
    double s = std::sin(theta);
    double x = this->values[0] * c + this->values[2] * s;
    double y = this->values[1];
    double z = -(this->values[0]) * s + this->values[2] * c;

    return Vec<T, C>(x, y, z);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::rotateZ(double angle) const {

    VEC_ASSERT(C == 3);

    double theta = angle / 180.0 * M_PI;
    double c = std::cos(theta);
    double s = std::sin(theta);
    double x = this->values[0] * c - this->values[1] * s;
    double y = this->values[0] * s + this->values[1] * c;
    double z = this->values[2];

    return Vec<T, C>(x, y, z);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
auto Vec<T, C>::to_std_vector() const -> std::vector<dataType> {

    return std::vector<dataType>(&this->values[0], &this->values[0] + C);

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
template<typename TT, unsigned int CC>
Vec<TT, CC> Vec<T, C>::to() const {

    Vec<TT, CC> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < std::min(C, CC); ++i )
        result[i] = static_cast<TT>(this->values[i]);

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
auto Vec<T, C>::operator[](int index) -> dataType_ref {

    VEC_ASSERT(index < C);

    return this->values[index];

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
auto Vec<T, C>::operator()(int index) -> dataType_ref {

    VEC_ASSERT(index < C);

    return this->values[index];

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
auto Vec<T, C>::operator[](int index) const -> dataType_cref {

    VEC_ASSERT(index < C);

    return this->values[index];

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
auto Vec<T, C>::operator()(int index) const -> dataType_cref {

    VEC_ASSERT(index < C);

    return this->values[index];

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator+(T v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] + v;

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator-(T v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] - v;

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator*(T v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] * v;

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator/(T v) {

    VEC_ASSERT(v != 0);

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] / v;

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>& Vec<T, C>::operator+=(T v) {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] += v;

    return *this;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>& Vec<T, C>::operator-=(T v) {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] -= v;

    return *this;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>& Vec<T, C>::operator*=(T v) {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] *= v;

    return *this;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C>& Vec<T, C>::operator/=(T v) {

    VEC_ASSERT(v != 0);

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        this->values[i] /= v;

    return *this;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator+(const Vec<T, C>& v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] + v[i];

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator-(const Vec<T, C>& v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] - v[i];

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator*(const Vec<T, C>& v) {

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] * v[i];

    return result;

}

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
Vec<T, C> Vec<T, C>::operator/(const Vec<T, C>& v) {

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        VEC_ASSERT(v[i] != 0);

    Vec<T, C> result;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i )
        result[i] = this->values[i] / v[i];

    return result;

}

typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i;
typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef Vec<int, 4> Vec4i;

typedef Vec<unsigned int, 2> Vec2u;
typedef Vec<unsigned int, 3> Vec3u;
typedef Vec<unsigned int, 4> Vec4u;

typedef Vec<float, 2> Vec2f;
typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
typedef Vec<float, 4> Vec4f;

typedef Vec<double, 2> Vec2d;
typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
typedef Vec<double, 4> Vec4d;

typedef Vec<char, 2> Vec2c;
typedef Vec<char, 3> Vec3c;
typedef Vec<char, 4> Vec4c;

typedef Vec<unsigned char, 2> Vec2uc;
typedef Vec<unsigned char, 3> Vec3uc;
typedef Vec<unsigned char, 4> Vec4uc;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your edits. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: @SamOnela Sure, I will change it back.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: @SamOnela Okay. I just thought I should include what rsy56640 suggested.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? Can I assume C++17?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Well, I think I don't use anything from C++17 in `Vec`. If you mean the compiler, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally a *real* vector class :P.

1. Any reason why you use `VEC_ASSERT` instead of just `assert`. I don't really see the advantage of doing so.
2. `using` declarations are nicer than `typedef`s IMO:

   ```
   using dataType = T;
   ```
3. If you use exceptions, mark functions that don't or shouldn't throw `noexcept`.
4. Make use of the [*injected-class-name*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name):

   ```
   Vec cross(const Vec &v) const;
   ```
5. You should implement all the `@=` operators for vectors. Also unary `-`.
6. Use standard algorithms:

   ```
   std::fill(values, values + C, 0); // default constructor, second one too
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), values); // std::vector constructor, init list
   std::inner_product(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 0); // length/dot
   std::transform(values, values + C, result.values, [length](const auto& value) {
     return values / length;
   }); // norm, operator@
   assert(std::all_of(v.values, v.values + C, [](const auto& value) {
     return value != 0;
   })); // operator/
   ```
7. You don't have to use `this->` everywhere you know :).
8. You should consider using `assert` messages: `assert(v[0] == 0 && "the first element must be 0!");`
9. No love for `long double` and `signed char`? They don't have aliases.
10. You don't fill the rest of the elements to 0 in your `std::vector`, initializer list constructors and in `to`.
11. You don't need `push` by changing your signature a bit and doing:

    ```
    template <typename T, unsigned int C>
    template <typename... Args>
    Vec<T, C>::Vec(Args&&... args) : Vec{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {
      static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= C, "too many arguments to vector");
    }
    ```
12. There are techniques to avoid implementing similar code between `operator@` and `operator@=`:

    ```
    friend Foo operator+(Foo lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
      lhs += rhs;
      return lhs;
    }
    Foo& operator+=(const Foo& rhs) const {
      // do logic
      return *this;
    }
    ```

    More information very good advice for overloading operator can be found on [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).
13. If you want you can reduce the code duplicate of cv qualified `operator[]`s by using `const_cast`.
14. Please prohibit creating a vector of length 0! :)
15. You could provide rvalue overloads of `operator[]` to enable efficient moving, but you don't have to. This is overkill, mostly used in the standard library. Have a look at [`std::optional::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) to see this in action.
16. You might want to consider adding a constructor that takes a pair of iterators, so that `Vec` can be initialized by anything really, not just a `std::vector`.
17. Consider making everything `constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestions. 1) No, there was something else I wanted to do and I didn't, unfortunately I can't re-post the code. 2) I could use `using`, 3) yes, I will use exceptions, 4) does this work for the implementation as well? 5) if you mean `==, !=, <, >` etc, I will. I am just thinking 2 possible ways: a) `==` returns `true` or `false` if both vectors are the same or not and b) `==` returns a vector of bools (like matlab does) 6) yes, I should and I will, 7) I know, it's just my style, 8) I am still thinking if I should go with assert or exceptions or both (any suggestion)?

Comment: @DimChtz 5) Oh yeah that too. I meant `Vec& operator+=(const Vec&)`

Comment: 9) Yes, eventually I will add more aliases, 10) True, I will fix this, 11)  Nice, I didn't know this, 12) will do that too, 13) i didn't think of that :P, 14) I was thinking of that, should I use `enable_if`?, 15) I think I lost you here :P, 16) I will

Comment: @DimChz Use asserts for precondition violation. I'd use asserts in your case, because they should be guaranteed by the caller.

Comment: Yes, I will eventually include everything. I am still doing changes

Comment: So, now exceptions at all?

Comment: @DimChz there is no definite and objective answer, but I vote for no.

Comment: @Rakette Question: When I have a better "version" of this (adding stuff, implementing suggestions) should I make a new question posting the new code for further suggestions? As far as I understand I shouldn't re-post code on the same question.

Comment: @DimChtz Exactly. Please post a new question. Updating your code once it is posted is not allowed.

Comment: @Rakette Can't do 16 because the constructor with 2 iterators conflicts with the constructor with 2 `T` args.

Comment: @DimChtz SFINAE to the rescue! Have a look at  `std::iterator_traits`

Comment: @Rakette Actually, I used this: `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Iter>::value>::type*` which seems to work.

Comment: @DimChtz Are you sure? An iterator is not an integral type necessarily

Comment: @Rakette1111 No no, look again: `!std::is_integral`.

Comment: @DimChtz yes, still wrong. What if I have a vector of a type that is not an integral (e.g. a infinite precision number). If that's outside your intended usage, then it's okay of course :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82240/discussion-between-dimchtz-and-rakete1111).

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T, unsigned int C>
class Vec;
```

The template generates redundant codes if `C` varies for the same `T`.
You can look through `<<Effective C++>> Item 44` and refactor like this:

```
template<typename T>
class VecBase {
    T* data;
public:
    VecBase(std::size_t C);
};

template<typename T, unsigned int C>
class Vec :VecBase<T> {
public:
    Vec() :VecBase<T>(C)
    {}
};
```

The benefit is:

- prevent software from being too large.
- shrink the size of `Vec<T, C>` (data is allocated on the heap, just contains a pointer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I use `VecBase` only for storing the data and keep everything else inside `Vec`?

Comment: Right, and remember to correctly implement copy/move/dtor.

Comment: I think this: `Vec() :VecBase(C)` should be: `Vec() : VecBase<T>(C)`.

Comment: Please don't use the term heap it is not meaningful in a C++ context (Don't be fooled because Java uses these terms). There is no reference to heap/stack in the C++ standard for a good reason. The terms you should be using are automatic/static/dynamic storage duration objects. Here the difference is between automatic and dynamic objects.